# FilterPopup needs to resize in Telerik RadGridView

Tags: wpf, filter, popup, telerik, radgridview

I am using WPF Telerik RadGridView. I want to resize the filterpopup width like column resizing. I am not able to see any properties. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that they have this feature built-in. I believe that the best option is to customize the template by adding drag `Thumb` element and handle the resizing with several lines of custom logic in the drag handlers. Also you can check the [article about the template structure](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/styles-and-templates/styling-filteringcontrol).